# Query to get all items assigned to me in a tree with all parents (of all levels)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a query that give me a list of all my assigned items + all parents (until root parent).

Assume following items in tfs:

```
- Feature 1
-- Product Back Log Item 1-1
--- Task 1-1-1
--- Task 1-1-2 (assigned to me)
--- Task 1-1-3
-- Product Back Log Item 1-2
--- Task 1-2-1 (assigned to me)
--- Task 1-2-2
--- Task 1-2-3
-- Product Back Log Item 1-3
--- Task 1-3-1
--- Task 1-3-2
--- Task 1-3-3
- Feature 2
-- Product Back Log Item 2-1
--- Task 2-1-1
--- Task 2-1-2
--- Task 2-1-3
- Feature 3
-- Product Back Log Item 3-1
--- Task 3-1-1
--- Task 3-1-2
--- Task 3-1-3 (assigned to me)
```

How can i write a query that results me following output:

```
- Feature 1
-- Product Back Log Item 1-1
--- Task 1-1-2 (assigned to me)
-- Product Back Log Item 1-2
--- Task 1-2-1 (assigned to me)
- Feature 3
-- Product Back Log Item 3-1
--- Task 3-1-3 (assigned to me)
```

Is this possible in Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is not too hard to do. Create a new query, set the type to "Tree of Workitems" and set the Child filter to include `assigned to=@me`. Set the drop down on the bottom right to: "match linked work item first".

[image]

Comment: This is not the solution, because the result outputs Feature 2. But Feature 2 is not assigned to me nor any child of them.

Comment: Hmz in that case you may need to set it to match child-first in the filter options.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Changing filter options solve my problem. I have updated your answer.